# What is exact result of the fusion of notmaxed pets?

Tags: realm-of-the-mad-god

According to the [pet tool](http://pfiffel.com/pets/#Gold%20Bulldog) if I fuse 70/70 rare pet for 70/65 i will get legendary 70/67 pet. The exact same result is promised for 70/70 + 70/64 fusion. So I wonder, will the legendary pet get 67th level of 2nd ability partially maxed or will it be exactly at 0 (I mean, at the beginning of the 67th level)? If the first case is true, then how many feed power will the 2nd ability get after the fusion?

Comment: Could you please rephrase this? I don't understand what you mean by "how many feed power will the 2nd ability get after the fusion?"

Comment: @Vanguard66, when you feed pet you see current level blue line, which shows the progress for current level. Right? So the question is about this blue line, will it be at 0 (extremely short) or it can be in a middle, depending on what you have before fusion.

Comment: @Vanguard66, Similarly you can check on realmeye number of feed power "Points" fed to your pet. I mean exactly this number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the new level will not be partially maxed.

I fused 70/65th pet (as target) with 70/70th pet. First had 36452 points in it's 2nd ability, second had 57840 points, this makes the average number of points 47146. But the result was 70/67/1 pet with all levels at 0, so 2nd ability had only 39921, according to the value of 67th level.